# unable accessing /solr on jetty

Tags: database, solr, jetty

I am trying to run solr following schema I had in solr 1.4 to solr 3.5 and when I add core and schema to 3.5 : "500" error is found

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    Severe errors in solr configuration.

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: 

 <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in solr.xml

-------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No system property or default value specified for solr.solr.home
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.DOMUtil.substituteProperty(DOMUtil.java:331)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.DOMUtil.substituteProperties(DOMUtil.java:284)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.DOMUtil.substituteProperties(DOMUtil.java:292)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.DOMUtil.substituteProperties(DOMUtil.java:292)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:132)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:430)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

my core configuration looks like :

```
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="geoplanet" instanceDir="solr-geoplanet"/>
<property name="dataDir" value="solr-geoplanet/data" />
```

Is there any extra configuration changes required to move from solr1.5 to solr3.1?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is hardcode the property value as provided in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1007

Answer (score 1):

For Exception -

As per exception, Solr unable to get value for `solr.solr.home`. So while starting the Solr pass JVM param, for example: `-Dsolr.solr.home=/usr/solr/home`

Solr 1.5 to 3.1 -

While migration, you will need to add the following config in your solrconfig.xml `<luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_31</luceneMatchVersion>`